# Selenium 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'Get_Attribute'

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium webdriver (chrome) with Python, I'm trying to get the **href** from all the links on the webpage. When I try the following:

```
items = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
print items

for item in items:
    href = item.Get_Attribute('href')
    print href
```

It manages to get all the links, but on get_attribute I get an error:

> 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'Get_Attribute'

Though everywhere I looked it seems like it should work.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The "Get_Attribute" property doesn't exist, but the "get_attribute" property does:

```
items = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
print items

for item in items:
    href = item.get_attribute('href')
    print href
```

Answer (score 3):

For python with input-field is like:

```
nowText = driver.find_element_by_id("source").get_attribute("value")
print(nowText)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
src = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img").get_attribute("src")
```

Answer (score 0):

For [the latest Selenium version](https://pythoninoffice.com/fixing-attributeerror-webdriver-object-has-no-attribute-find_element_by_xpath/#:%7E:text=Fix%20%23%202%20%E2%80%93%20Update%20Our%20Code%20(And%20Use%20the%20Latest%20Version%20of%20Selenium)) the method find_element_by_id is deprecated, find_element should be used and the same happens to get_attribute instead of getAttribute.

Answer (score -1):

in the latest version
find_element_by_id is deprecated, find_element should be used

```html
# Import Selenium's WebDriver module
from selenium import webdriver

# Create a WebDriver object
driver = webdriver. Chrome()

# Use the get method of the WebDriver object to open the specified URL
driver.get("https://www.example.com")

# Use the find_element method to get the specified element
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "input-id")

# Get the text in the element
text = element.text
print(text)

# Close the WebDriver object
driver. quit()
```

Comment: The question is about attribute method, not .text method